# Flex items are not centering with justify-content but centered with text-align?

Tags: html, css

I don't understand Why `justify-content:center` not working?

I think it's a inputs width issue i already tried give width to input fields but still not working.

Here is my code:

```css
    .container {
    width: 100vw;
    }
    .container form {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    .container form input {
    width: 80%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="" method="post" novalidate>
    <div>
      <label for="my_username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="username" class="inputs" autofocus required id="my_username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="my_email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" id="my_email">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="my_password1">Password1:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password1" class="inputs" required id="my_password1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="my_password2">Confirm Password:</label>
      <input type="password" name="password2" class="inputs" required id="my_password2">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`justify-content` defines the alignment along the main axis (in your case `column`. So you are centering the content within its row.

It also works only for the direct decendents of the `flex` container (in this case the `div` elements that are direct children of the `form`. If you change `justify-content` to `align-items` (which works for the cross-axis) then this should center the `div` elements horizontally, and then you can add the `css` to align the `label` and `input` elements within those `div`s.

There's a really good guide available for the properties of `flex-box` and what they affect [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

```css
.container {
  width: 100vw;
}
.container form {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
.container form input {
  width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Why the main axis is column in my case? How can we identify the main aixs?

Comment: @TariqAhmed - Due to `flex-direction: column;`. The default is `row`, but this is the direction that the flex children are layed out in.

Comment: It means if ```flex-direction: row;``` then our main axis is horizontal?

Comment: That's right. From the linked article:`flex-direction` establishes the main-axis, thus defining the direction flex items are placed in the flex container. Flexbox is (aside from optional wrapping) a single-direction layout concept. Think of flex items as primarily laying out either in horizontal rows or vertical columns.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved if you use `align-items` instead of `justify-content`. It's because of `justify-content` works in main axis and `align-items` in cross-axis, perpendicular to the main axis.

```css
.container form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: Put the reason..

Comment: @TariqAhmed edited.